# Karate [Functional Automation and Performance Scripts are running in simultaneously

Tags: api, karate

Has anybody here experienced updating POM of the functional automation project with Karate-Gatling to be able to re-use functional scripts for performance but when executed both of the tests are triggered?

```
mvn test "-Dkarate.env=dev" -Dkarate.options="--tags @FunctionalScript classpath:services/project/functional.feature" -Dtest=TestRunner
```

The above mvn is supposed to run only the functional automation script, but the performance scripts are also getting triggered right after that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: apologise for overlooking that, Peter. that's embarrassing. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how you set up the maven project. If you have the following snippet in your gatling plugin setup, remove it:

```
  <executions>
      <execution>
          <phase>test</phase>
          <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
          </goals>
      </execution>
  </executions>
```

Explained in detail here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-gatling#maven

Comment: Thanks Peter for sharing the detailed explanation link! Appreciate the help as usual.